# Can SQLite and MySQL work in one android application?

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

I am  currently creating an android that will use SQLite offline and MySQL when the mobile phone in connected in a network or intranet.

Is it possible? If not can you suggest other methods?

Thank You and appreciate the help

Comment: Do you mean sqlite as offline local storage and when app is online you would be able to connect to mysql server? Right ?

Comment: Yes. I'm still trying to learn SQLite and I haven't tried using MySQL in a android application

Answer (score 0):

You're describing a distributed database.  The pattern that works best in this case is to ensure your app goes uses the local SQLite database for all data presented to the user.  You don't want your app to be waiting for MySQL data - the user might decide to walk into an elevator and lose coverage, or whatever.

Use a background thread to keep the MySQL data synchronized with your local SQLite data, and use notifications to tell the app when new data is available for display.